# How to autoscale Kubernetes on AWS

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubeadm

I created kubernetes cluster on aws ec2 using kubeadm. Now I need to autoscale the K8's cluster when there are not enough resources on nodes to schedule new pods, How can I achieve autoscaling feature for my cluster?

Comment: How is [the cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/cluster-autoscaler-1.12.2/cluster-autoscaler#cluster-autoscaler) not the [first search result](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cluster+autoscaler) for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a great answer if you mean you manually ran `kubeadm` on some EC2 instance. `cluster-autoscaler` is the thing to use, but it requires you deploy your nodes using Autoscaling Groups. It's possible to use ASGs and `kubeadm` but I don't know of anything off-the-shelf for it.